# mCustomScrollBar doesn't work until i resize the browser

Tags: jquery

I have div(display:none) end on gallery click i am making it visible( slide Down) and i am loading the custom scroll bar (I also tried to use 'update' as input argument but it didn't work). Here is the example of my code:

```
$(".ID").click(function () {
    $('#LinkDiv31').delay(600).slideDown(1000);
    $("#GallerySmallSide").mCustomScrollbar();
});

<div id="LinkDiv31" style="width:230px;height:100%;background-color:#FFFFFF;opacity:0.99;display:none;z-index:3; left:calc(0.7% + 201px); position: relative;">
    <div class="ScrollClass" id='GallerySmallSide' style=" overflow-y:auto; width:98%;height:100%;position:absolute;z-index:4;top:10px;left:15px">
        <div class="chooseGalery2" style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #000;cursor:pointer;background:url(./some.jpg); opacity:0.90;width:200px;height:112.5px;background-size:100%;" onmouseover="this.style.opacity='1';" onmouseout="this.style.opacity='0.90'"></div>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8A3pk/2/

Comment: can u make a fiddle ?

Comment: i'll try just a moment

Comment: You forgot to add the mcustomscrollbar.js (or what is the file name) file to The Fiddle. Fixed it, here is the fiddle with the plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/8A3pk/3/

Comment: Try `$("#GallerySmallSide").mCustomScrollbar({
        advanced: {
            updateOnContentResize: true,
            updateOnBrowserResize: true
        }
    });`

Comment: it startet showing but it's not normal onload i habve to scroll upwards to get to the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the scroll call function as a callback on the slideDown and it worked as a charm:

```
    $('#LinkDiv31').slideDown(1000,function(){

       $(".ScrollClass").mCustomScrollbar();

    });
```